# How Azure Loadbalancer will serve files from primary VMs?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, cloud, virtual-machine, iaas

I have a primary VM and 3 load balancer VMs, If i want to deploy my code, do i need to deploy in all the VMs? If not how the deployed files in primary VM is served to diff load balancer VMs in-case of primary VM is down.

Because If we deployed files in one VM, that server itself is down, then how other load balancer VMs will pick the files and serve. or Is this handled in diff way?

Comment: please a) reformat your question that its better readable. b) add some more details as its not clear what you are really asking

Comment: you should rather use a VM scaleset . you will deploy once and it will be replicated in all instances. Or you could try the custom image option if that is suitable to your requirement.